# iOS Pocket API - Reading Own Pocket Article In Web View Or Actual Pocket App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, pocket

I have an app where users can sign into their own Pocket Account and read their own saved articles in various modes with their reading speed being timed, allowing them to continually progress and become faster and more efficient readers. One of the modes is simply normal Article Mode, where they can read the whole article as it is.

Pocket's API does not provide the full text of the article. I've tried numerous free text parsing APIs, and they don't parse article text too well, and Diffbot is way too expensive ($300 a month!).

Is there a way I can work around this issue? I'm thinking of somehow opening the article in the user's Pocket App OR using a `UIWebView` to automatically go to that user's article at getpocket.com if these solutions are possible.

Any help or advice on how to get this done would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried https://www.readability.com/ ?

You can also try SFSafariViewController (iOS 9 only), you can use the reader mode of Safari.